# How to fix position in jquery draggable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-draggable

I am retrieving images from mysql data and putting them up in ul li. Now i am making a div which will have items draggable via jquery. What i want is when user changes the position, it should automatically be saved. As in it shouldn't be like the way it was first time.

Comment: edit your question and explain more about users and data.

Comment: I have edited. Check. @MostafaShahverdy

Comment: so you have to save `left`, and `top` position of image every time when user is dragging the image.

Comment: How to do that? @sourcecode

Answer (score 2):

First you need to save save positions for each user to be saved in database. in order to change the position you need something like this:

```
$('#draggable').position().top = yourSavedPosition;
```

After each drag you must send an Ajax request to your server that holds position for each object.

Answer (score 1):

Use CSS:

```
#draggable{
    position:fixed !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to do like this:

`wherever user  is dragging image`,

-> find the coordinates

->and then `enter` those coordinates in `top` and `left` positions

```
$( ".selector" ).draggable({
   stop: function(event, ui) {

  var x = ui.instance.element.position();
  $("#image1").css({"position":"fixed","left":x.left,"top":x.top});
 }
});
```